# How can I initialize H2 once for all DataJpaTests

Tags: spring-boot-test, data-jpa-test

I have hundreds `@DataJpaTest`-annotated classes within my spring boot library and it seems that every single class initializes/drops the schema.

How can I initialize (and eventually drops) the schema for all test classes?

```java
// I have 1500 classes look like this

class SomeDataJpaTest {
}

class SomeOtherDataJpaTest {
}

...
```

I tried with the [`@Suite`](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/api/org.junit.platform.suite.api/org/junit/platform/suite/api/Suite.html) and had no luck.

```java
@SuiteDisplayName("DataJpaTest")
@IncludeClassNamePatterns({
        "^.*DataJpaTest$"
})
@SelectPackages({
        "com.....jpa.domain",
        "com.....jpa.repository"
})
@Suite
class _DataJpaTestSuite {

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my perspective, it's better for each class to drop the schema and re-create since you make sure that your integration tests are not coupled and do not affect how your classes behave (which is the purpose of an end-to-end test).

However, one thing you can try is to do the following:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@DataJpaTest
public abstract class BaseDataJpaTest {
  // add initialization logic here
}
```

In the case of having test-containers, or a specific configuration of your h2 database write your instead of the comments

```
@BeforeClass
public static void setup() {
  // initialization logic here
}
```

Finally, for all test cases make it extend the `BaseDataJpaTest`

```
public class SomeDataJpaTest extends BaseDataJpaTest {
  // test methods here
}
```

As i mentioned before, you might need to make sure to clean up after each test to avoid affecting your other test cases.